# Java constructor of "immutable class" with many fields with default values?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class with lots of fields. They should basically be set at the constructor phase and never change. Semantically the class then is an immutable one.

```
public class A{
    final int a;
    final short b;
    final double e;
    final String f;
    final String g;
    //and more
}
```

The problem is that normally these fields have default values and therefore I do not want to always burden the user with a constructor with all of them.  Most time, they just need to set a couple of them.   There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. I would need lots  of constructor with different signature.
2. Create a bunch of set method of these field and only set those non-default value.  But this somehow indicate a different semantics other than immutable nature.
3. Create a new parameter class that is mutable and use that class as constructor.

None of that is totally satisfactory.  Is there any other approach?  Thanks.
One way

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use a combination of a parameter class and a fluent builder API for creating the parameter:

```
public class A {
    private final int a;
    private final short b;
    private final double e;
    private final String g;

    public static class Aparam {
        private int a = 1;
        private short b = 2;
        private double e = 3.141593;
        private String g = "NONE";

        public Aparam a(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }

        public Aparam b(short b) {
            this.b = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Aparam e(double e) {
            this.e = e;
            return this;
        }

        public Aparam g(String g) {
            this.g = g;
            return this;
        }

        public A build() {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }

    public static Aparam a(int a) {
        return new Aparam().a(a);
    }

    public static Aparam b(short b) {
        return new Aparam().b(b);
    }

    public static Aparam e(double e) {
        return new Aparam().e(e);
    }

    public static Aparam g(String g) {
        return new Aparam().g(g);
    }

    public static A build() {
        return new Aparam().build();
    }

    private A(Aparam p) {
        this.a = p.a;
        this.b = p.b;
        this.e = p.e;
        this.g = p.g;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "{a=" + a + ",b=" + b + ",e=" + e + ",g=" + g + "}";
    }
}
```

Then create instances of A like this:

```
A a1 = A.build();
A a2 = A.a(7).e(17.5).build();
A a3 = A.b((short)42).e(2.218282).g("fluent").build();
```

Class A is immutable, the parameters are optional, and the interface is fluent.

Comment: You don't even need getters in your builder, and A's constructor can be private. This also allows checking the parameters in the build() method instead of the constructor.

Comment: True. I considered making A's ctor private. That's probably cleaner.

Comment: Another advantage is that the builder can choose to return an instance of A, ABis or ATer (Abis and Ater being subclasses of A), depending on the parameters.

Comment: If you're not obsessed with fluency, you can just make the variables of the builder public. The calling code is slightly longer, but the definition of the builder is much briefer.

Comment: @TomAnderson You can leave them private; the outer class can still access them.

Comment: @JBNizet The builder can do that anyway; right now, its `build()` method is just calling A's ctor, but it could do anything it wants. I took your suggestions and made A's ctor private and removed the getters, and I also added convenience methods so you can just start writing `A.e(3).g("foo").a(23).build()` or even just `A.build()`.

Comment: If you make the constructor of A public, it allows creating an A from the builder, instead of letting the builder choose to build an Abis, because it's the appropriate subclass to create. In other words, you can't prevent a client doing `A a = new A(builder);` instead of `A a = builder.build();`

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, even with a private constructor, the inner class can still call it. That's what I'm doing in the current version, above, and it compiles.

Comment: @DavidConrad: You misunderstand me. I mean make the builder's fields public so the building code can set them directly. So `ABuilder ab = new ABuilder(); ab.foo = 7; A a = ab.build();`

Comment: @DavidConrad: And i think you misunderstand JB, too. He is suggesting making A's constructor private to prevent outside code from calling it, to force use of the builder.

Comment: @TomAnderson Ah, okay, I see. I wouldn't prefer that to a fluent API since I wouldn't want to break the object construction over multiple lines unnecessarily (if you were just calling a constructor, that would typically be on one line, and that's what we're trying to replace), but that is certainly another option. Cheers!

Comment: @TomAnderson I did make A's constructor private. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. In some sense, this builder/param class is a varient of my propose 3, but the fluent syntax is very nice.  Too bad there is no magic cure for the problem.

Comment: @zggame: the "magic cure", if you're willing to go that far, would be to use _another language_ that has e.g. named and default arguments, like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2075).

Comment: Just come across this article http://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/     .  It has an almost same idea, except putting the builder method in the builder inner class, which is semantically clearer in my mind.

Answer (score 19):

Two things you can do:

- Many constructor overloads
- Use a [builder object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Comment: I don't think the builder pattern is proper for an immutable class.

Comment: @zggame: of course not! You use a builder to build another object.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a semi-serious suggestion, but we can modify [mikera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11378969/116639) to be typesafe.

Say we have:

```
public class A {
    private final String foo;
    private final int bar;
    private final Date baz;
}
```

Then we write:

```
public abstract class AProperty<T> {
    public static final AProperty<String> FOO = new AProperty<String>(String.class) {};
    public static final AProperty<Integer> BAR = new AProperty<Integer>(Integer.class) {};
    public static final AProperty<Date> BAZ = new AProperty<Date>(Date.class) {};

    public final Class<T> propertyClass;

    private AProperty(Class<T> propertyClass) {
        this.propertyClass = propertyClass;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class APropertyMap {
    private final Map<AProperty<?>, Object> properties = new HashMap<AProperty<?>, Object>();

    public <T> void put(AProperty<T> property, T value) {
        properties.put(property, value);
    }
    public <T> T get(AProperty<T> property) {
        return property.propertyClass.cast(properties.get(property));
    }
}
```

Aficionados of advanced design patterns and/or obscure Java tricks will recognise this as a typesafe heterogeneous container. Just be grateful i didn't use `getGenericSuperclass()` as well.

Then, back in the target class:

```
public A(APropertyMap properties) {
    foo = properties.get(AProperty.FOO);
    bar = properties.get(AProperty.BAR);
    baz = properties.get(AProperty.BAZ);
}
```

This is all used like this:

```
APropertyMap properties = new APropertyMap();
properties.put(AProperty.FOO, "skidoo");
properties.put(AProperty.BAR, 23);
A a = new A(properties);
```

Just for the lulz, we can even give the map a fluent interface:

```
public <T> APropertyMap with(AProperty<T> property, T value) {
    put(property, value);
    return this;
}
```

Which lets callers write:

```
A a = new A(new APropertyMap()
    .with(AProperty.FOO, "skidoo")
    .with(AProperty.BAR, 23));
```

There are lots of little improvements you could make to this. The types in `AProperty` could be handled more elegantly. `APropertyMap` could have a static factory instead of a constructor, allowing a more fluent style of code, if you're into that sort of thing. `APropertyMap` could grow a `build` method which calls `A`'s constructor, essentially turning it into a builder.

You can also make some of these objects rather more generic. `AProperty` and `APropertyMap` could have generic base classes which did the functional bits, with very simple `A`-specific subclasses.

If you're feeling particularly enterprise, and your domain objects were JPA2 entities, then you could use the metamodel attributes as the property objects. This leaves the map/builder doing a bit more work, but it's still pretty simple; i have a generic builder working in 45 lines, with a subclass per entity containing a single one-line method.

Comment: Nice.  I love the static typing. Good compromise, I might be able to use it for another case where we have a giant Map<String,object>.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't actually need the Class instances to cast on the way out as type safety is enforced with the put method requiring the property type and value to match. An unchecked cast can be used instead without compromising safety. The advantage of omitting using the class object is that it works for objects with generics such as List properly where you cannot provide a type safe class object.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting option is to create a constructor that takes a `Map<String,Object>` as input which contains the values that the user wants to specify.

The constructor can use the value provided in the map if present, or a default value otherwise.

**EDIT:**

I think the random downvoters have completely missed the point - this isn't always going to be the best choice but it is a useful technique that has several advantages:

- It is concise and avoids the need to create separate constructors / builder classes
- It allows easy programmatic construction of parameter sets (e.g. if you are constructing objects from a parsed DSL)
- This is a technique that is frequently used and proven to work in dynamic languages. You just need to write decent tests (which you should be doing anyway!)

Comment: this leads to many errors, mainly with type compatibility, I would say that in this case a builder approach would be better (as suggested by Jordão)

Comment: Well it's a technique from dynamic languages.... you are trading static type checking for convenience/flexibility. Up to you if you like the approach, but I've found it's not a problem if you write good tests.

Comment: That's the JavaScript way, and good in languages with dynamic typing, but I wouldn't do it in Java.  Could work if all the arguments were the same type maybe.  Still, I think Bob Martin has something to say about "passing hash maps around" not being a good idea.  Neither -1 or +1.

Comment: In my opinion, an approach like this goes against everything Java stands for.

Comment: It not only gives up static typing, it's fragile because if you accidentally misspell a parameter you get no indication you did anything wrong unless you have a catch-all case that throws if there are any unexpected values in the map.

Comment: There are ways to do things like this which are not so bad (eg define an enum which enumerates the properties of the object, and use instances of that as keys), but it's probably no easier than a builder.

Comment: It isn't really concise. It makes the class more concise, but the client code more verbose since there's no syntax to statically initialize a map in Java. That's not the case in the other languages like Ruby and Python where this pattern is more common. As for catching errors with tests, you will always be paying the penalty at run time because you always need to catch the case where a misspelled parameter is ignored in addition to testing that a correctly spelled parameter is picked up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Having many fields could be an indication that one class does too much.

Maybe you can split the class up in several immutable classes and pass instances of these classes to the constructors of the other classes. This would limit the number of constructors.